# displaying labels for form objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label, nested-forms, simple-form

I have this problem with this nested form when it comes to displaying the question (q_text) and the only hack ive found is to use text_area, then it works

```
<%= f.fields_for :answered_questions do |a| %>
  <%= a.check_box :answer %>
  <%= a.text_field :q_text %>
<% end %>
```

here is how this looks : http://postimage.org/image/azrbgidht/

but i dont want to use `text_field` - since its for input but not showing text like i want

if i change the line to `<%= a.label :q_text %>` i get this : http://postimage.org/image/l4pz62w29/

How can i make the form object understand that the label is supposed to be the questions text (q_text) but not just `q_text` ?

**UPDATE**

i changed the code to use `simple_form` but now the label dosnt display at all

```
<%= simple_form_for(@test_session) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :answered_questions do |ff| %>

    <%= ff.check_box :answer, :label => ff.object.q_text %> 

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can have a label AND a text_field.

Comment: i dont really want the text_field but just a label, the check_box handles the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fixed it, apparently i cant use inline labels and form objects at the same time

`<%= f.simple_fields_for :answered_questions do |ff| %>`

`<%= ff.check_box :answer %>`

`<%= ff.label ff.object.q_text %>`

`<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Write as following.

<%= a.label :q_text,"questions text" %>
```

Comment: i dont want to set the `:q_text` attribute here, but get its value from the `:answered_questions` model

Comment: Yes, you can do. <%= a.label "#{your object from answered_questions}" %> may work.

Comment: im not sure im doing this right but if i have `<%= a.label "#{a.q_text}" %>` i get undefined method `q_text' for nested form

Comment: Yes, as you have used the form object. So you got that error.